# Expo React Native watchPositionAsync fires multiple times

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I am using watchPositionAsync to get the location of the user and update the state, this works fine but when the app is in the background and re-opened, it seems to fire multiple times causing my screen to refresh, it also ignored the 10 second interval.

Is there any way to fix this? It seems to be a problem on Android and iOS

```
  async componentDidMount() {
        this._getlocation();
     }


 _getlocation = async () => {

  const { status } = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.LOCATION)

  this.watchLocation = await Location.watchPositionAsync(
             {
                 distanceInterval: 15,
                 accuracy:6,
                 timeInterval: 10000
             },
             location => {
             let coords = location.coords;
             this.setState({userLocation: location})
             this.fetchItems();

           },
           error => console.log(error)
         );

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add "isRunning: false" to the component state and try to use the following edition:

```
async componentDidMount() {
    if(this.state.isRunning === false) {  // <----- ADDED ------------------------
        this._getlocation();
    }
}

_getlocation = async () => {
    const { status } = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.LOCATION);
    this.setState({ isRunning: true });  // <----- ADDED ------------------------
    this.watchLocation = await Location.watchPositionAsync(
        {
            distanceInterval: 15,
            accuracy:6,
            timeInterval: 10000
        },
        location => {
            let coords = location.coords;
            this.setState({userLocation: location})
            this.fetchItems();
        },
        error => console.log(error)
    );
}
```